# How to repeat a code block for different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have four empty lists and a dictionary as shown below:

```
argv1_a=[]
argv1_b=[]
argv2_a=[]
argv2_b=[]
dic={'1':['1','x','build'],'2':['x','8','demolish'],'3':['3','x','build'],'4':['6','10','demolish']}
```

And a code block (it basically appends dictionary's values into lists and changes their types to int):

```
for i in dic.values():
    if i[2]=='build':
        if i[0]!='x':
            argv1_a.append(int(i[0]))
        else:
            argv1_a.append(i[0])
    elif i[2]=='demolish':
        if i[0]!='x':
            argv1_b.append(int(i[0]))
        else:
            argv1_b.append(i[0])
for i in dic.values():
    if i[2]=='build':
        if i[1]!='x':
            argv2_a.append(int(i[1]))
        else:
            argv2_a.append(i[1])
    elif i[2]=='demolish':
        if i[1]!='x':
            argv2_b.append(int(i[1]))
        else:
            argv2_b.append(i[1])
```

Here is the final results of the lists:

```
argv1_a=[1, 3]
argv1_b=['x', 6]
argv2_a=['x', 'x']
argv2_b=[8, 10]
```

Is there a better way to do that without writing the same code block and without using 3rd party libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in tuples, and use a `for` loop:

```
for (a, b, offset) in ((argv1_a, argv1_b, 0), (argv2_a, argv2_b, 1)):
    for i in dic.values():
        if i[2]=='build':
            if i[offset]!='x':
                a.append(int(i[offset]))
            else:
                a.append(i[offset])
        elif i[2]=='demolish':
            if i[offset]!='x':
                b.append(int(i[offset]))
            else:
                b.append(i[offset])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just define two dicts `d1` and `d2` containing argv1_a / argv2_a for the key `build`  and argv1_b / argv2_b for the key `demolish`, you can simplify your code as follows

```
>>> argv1_a=[]
>>> argv1_b=[]
>>> argv2_a=[]
>>> argv2_b=[]
>>>  dic = {'1': ['1', 'x', 'build'], '2': ['x', '8', 'demolish'], '3': ['3', 'x', 'build'], '4': ['6', '10', 'demolish']}

>>> d1 = dict(build=argv1_a, demolish=argv1_b)
>>> d2 = dict(build=argv2_a, demolish=argv2_b)
>>> for x, y, key in dic.values():
...     d1[key].append(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x)
...     d2[key].append(int(y) if y.isdigit() else y)
... 

>>> print (argv1_a, argv1_b, argv2_a, argv2_b)
[1, 3] ['x', 6] ['x', 'x'] [8, 10]
```